# struct is not returned properly from a function on c

Tags: c, ubuntu, input, struct, segmentation-fault

I have the following on lubuntu:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct fields{
  int hostNumber;
  int *numberArray;
};

struct fields *start();
struct fields *gatherData();
void sendMessageToOtherProcesses(struct fields *);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  struct fields *myFields;
  
  myFields = start();    
  return 0;
}

struct fields *start(){
  int input;
  struct fields *myFields;
  printf("1) Type 1 For Execution\n");
  printf("2) Type 2 For Exit\n");
  printf("Give your choice:");
  scanf("%d",&input);
  switch(input){
    case 1:
        myFields = gatherData();
        break;
    case 2:
    default:
        exit(0);
  }
  return myFields;
}

struct fields *gatherData(){
  int host;
  struct fields *myFields;

    printf("Give the host of the number to be checked if they are ordered:");
    scanf("%d",&host);


  int nmbArray[host];

  for (int i = 0; i < host; i++){
    printf("Give the %d number:", i);
    scanf("%d", &nmbArray[i]);
   // printf("array=%d\n", nmbArray[i]); 
  }  

  myFields->hostNumber = host; 
  myFields->numberArray = &nmbArray[0];
  for (int i = 0; i < (myFields->hostNumber) ; i++){
    printf("array=%d\n", (*(myFields->numberArray)));
    (myFields->numberArray)++;
  }    

  return myFields;

}
```

And I take segmentation fault. Any suggestion. Also take a look on the for loop , I can;t take the numbers from the array stored via input. On windows runs perfectly on mingw64 but i now i am on a lubuntu 32bit 18.10 machine.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to allocate the structure before dereferencing the pointer.

```
  myFields = malloc(sizeof(*myFields)); /* add this to allocate memory */
  myFields->hostNumber = host; 
  myFields->numberArray = &nmbArray[0];
```

Checking if `malloc()` is successful will make your code better:

```
  myFields = malloc(sizeof(*myFields));
  if (myFields == NULL) return NULL; /* add this to check if malloc() is successful */
  myFields->hostNumber = host; 
  myFields->numberArray = &nmbArray[0];
```

Another point is that the array

```
  int nmbArray[host];
```

will be deleted on returning from the function and pointers to that will become useless after that.

Allocate this dynamically instead:

```
  int* nmbArray = malloc(sizeof(*mnbArray) * host);
```

Then, after the loop, `myFields->numberArray` is changed to point at the element one past the last element of `nmbArray`, so set it again to `nmbArray` after the loop.
It can be done by doing

```
  myFields->numberArray = &nmbArray[0];
```

again.

Comment: Yes you were right, but if I want to iterate the myFields into start(), I get garbage instead the real data. Any suggestion?